# Casting pointer to multidimensional array

Tags: c++, casting

How do I cast a pointer to a multidimensional array?

E.g. `float*` to `float[][100][100]`?

```
float* f1(); // returns allocated memory (with data), suitable for processing by f2
void f2(float in[][100][100]);

float* p = f1();

f2( ???CAST??? p);
```

Comment: In C++ try and use `std::vector<float>` and emulate the 2D-ness, don't mess around with C-style arrays unless you have to.

Comment: @tadman I can't. `f1` and `f2` are from libraries that are not mine..

Comment: What a mess. Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's normally dangerous to do so, you can use [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) should you really want to:

```cpp
f2( reinterpret_cast<float(*)[100][100]> (p) );
```

Comment: tnx, I was trying `f2( reinterpret_cast<float[][100][100]> (p) );`, which did not compile...

Comment: @user2052436 Your problem is that an array with an unknown length is not a complete type, and that outside function arguments, there's no implicit array-to-pointer conversion, so the type must be `float(*)[100][100]`.

Comment: You could have used `float(&)[][100][100]` too, but then passing it would involve array-decay.